# Is it possible to authenticate when messaging inbox is clicked

Tags: android, sms, android-activity, inbox

I want to create an app where if the user tries to open the sms inbox then he must be asked to enter the saved password, basically setting password for built-in inbox application,

There are so many application in Google market where we can set password for some particular private contacts but not for the whole inbox as per my knowledge,but if it is available then how it is done?

Is it possible: to starting an activity where authentication is done if inbox is selected or intended to open

Answer (score 1):

Basically "No", you cannot control lifecycle of other applications without using hacks, bugs or rooting.

Comment: Then there is no way we can do for what i was asked?

Comment: No. Unless you exploit a android bug or something like this, framework should not let you interfere other applications that way.

Comment: Then i must change my concept of authentication,. then i will try to get authentication for private contacts messages only and not letting messages from private contact to go into inbox where everyone can see,..

Comment: But if anyone can provide me the solution then it would be appreciated ,thanks in advance

Comment: hello guys, i found an app in play store which will let me to control other app life cycle,steps the user has to do..       1)User can select which app has to be authenticated,          2)after setting password,i will open that app,automatically app asks for password,. so my question is:how can one app(app to authenticate) be launched when i actually opened another app(ex. "messaging app" or "file manager")

Comment: "without using hacks, bugs or rooting" is key in my answer.

Comment: "App Lock" is the app in play store which allow me to authenticate when my inbuilt "file manager" is opened.My phone is not rooted,and it has no bugs, so i am just asking what possible hacking method did they follow?how can they launch there app when i tried to open file manager?how did they manage to control life cycle of "file manager"?

Answer (score 0):

**It's Not Possible.**

Because think if Admin of phone have not set any authentication for his phone.like password asking or draw pattern or any other.Then what will you do at that time for security ? Your inbox will not secure.

For that you have to think other logic which can be secure which you actually want .ok